# jQuery masonry - call method after masonry reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I use Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery Masonry for a new site in developement. I append new elements to the container of masonry.

The elements are neither appended or prepended to existing children but in inserted in between them, depending on a sorting order like this:

```
var elem = $(boxes[rand2]);
$(".post").each(function(i){
    if(parseFloat($(this).data("weight"))<=weight){
        elem.insertBefore(this);
        return false;
    }
    else if (i == $(".post").length - 1) {
        elem.insertAfter(this);
        return false;
    }
});
```

This works perfect so far. What I'd like to achieve is that the elements only display when they reached their destination place. I don't want to disable animations, but the space for the new element should appear (empty) and only when everything is re-arranged through masonry the new element should appear.

I thought there would be a callback-action that fires after reload like this:

```
$('#posts').masonry('reload',function(){
  alert('re-aligning finished');
});
```

but that doesn't work, it fires to early.

So for the moment, I did

```
$('#posts').masonry('reload',function(){
  window.setTimeout(showElem,500);
});
function showPosts(){
  $('.post').show();
}
```

and that seems to work - but a fixed 500ms timeout is not a real beautiful solution...

So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're already using jQuery. Perhaps the use of [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects could be useful.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of what you're trying to solve? I'm guessing the .masonry function is a deferred object. so simply tying into that with a .done() might work... but im not sure if it returns a deferred. try it out

Comment: unfortunately this does not work :( maybe I just stick with my timeout of 500ms, it's not *that* bad but not beautiful

Answer (score 0):

Could you do it later after document loads?

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(documentReadyFunction);
$(window).resize(windowResizeFunction);
$(window).load(windowLoadFunction);
function documentReadyFunction() {
    //your inserted html here
}
function windowResizeFunction() {
    //resize here
}
function windowLoadFunction() {
    //do masonry here
}
})(jQuery);
```